# How can I tell if my computer has Windows 10 drivers?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, ssd

I want to buy a new SSD to clean install Windows 10 from a USB drive I created via the app on Windows' website. However, someone has warned me that my computer might not have the Windows 10 drivers.

How would I check this?

my laptop is a Samsung Series 7 Chronos (NP700Z5C-S02UB)

Comment: Windows 10 includes most drivers during install, then windows updates should find the rest. Post the make and specific model of your PC please.

Comment: I've posted the model in the OP

Comment: Check with the manufacturer.

Answer (score 2):

Your device [does not have Windows 10 drivers provided by Samsung](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/model/NP700Z5A-S01UK).

However as mentioned, most drivers are included in Windows 10, so if you do want to run Win 10, I would make a backup, upgrade and see if everything is working. if not you will have to restore as this is quite an old device.

Comment: which specific drivers from my computer, as of now, should I download copies of and put them onto a USB drive for when I go to SSD? I'm looking in the device manager and there's an awful lot of them. Should I download the installation files, and then put them on a USB stick? how would I run them if I needed to?

Comment: @KrissyMichaelsson Just download the drivers after you installed Windows.

Comment: What do on so about the Wi-Fi driver to even get to the internet?